# Required to access non-static member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call a function from one script into another but I'm getting:
An object reference is required to access non-static member `FireBlock.FireOn()`

The script with the function I am trying to call is `FireBlock` containing this which is attached to a box collider attached to a game object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FireBlock : MonoBehaviour {
public void FireOn ()
{
    collider.enabled=false;
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to call it in the other script.

```
void Update ()
{

    FireBlock.FireOn ();
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I've tried making the FireOn function public static, just void but nothings working.

Comment: You may want to learn the difference between static and non-static methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: unity does not work this way, you may check Unity3D documentation to how to pass objects to scripts.

Comment: when you made it public static; how did you try to invoke it? What do you mean my nothings working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create instance of `FireBlock` and then call the method with that instance.

```
FireBlock fireBlock = new FireBlock();
fireBlock.FireOn();
```

Since `FireOn` is an instance method you can't call it with the class name. You can only do that for `static` methods.

Comment: This is a unity3D specific question and the answer you have provided does not resolve the problem. The actual problem is passing a gameObject to a script which is well documented in Unity reference.

Comment: @daryal, I don't have idea about Unity, What the OP was trying to do is not possible in C# and I told him/her that it needs an instance of the class to invoke instance member, Now its upto OP to pass it or create one.

Comment: there is the tag of Unity3D, thus this is not simply a c# question. I think each answer shall point to a solution to the specific problem, not a generic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to access a mono behavior, you first need to access the GameObject..

There are a few ways to do this, here are your main tools.

```
GameObject.Find(name string) 



GameObject.FindWithTag(tag string)
```

Once you have your gameobject, now you need to get the script.  You do this with  `GetComponent<>()`

All together it looks like this '

```
FireBlock MyFireBlock = GameObject.Find("mygameobject").GetComponent<FireBlock>() ;
```

Or

```
GameObject mygameobject = GameObject.Find("mygameobject") ; 


FireBlock MyFireBlock  = Mygameobject.GetComponent <FireBlock>();
```

`